# How to Use AspectJ's @DeclareError in Kotlin + Spring boot + Intellij Environment?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, aspectj

I'm Trying to use @DeclareError annotation to detect method and make compile error which not use annotation like this :

```
@Pointcut("execution(public String com.example.checkloggingannotation.SampleController.*(..))")
   fun testError(){}

   @DeclareError("testError()")
   val getTestError = "test error"

   @Around("testError()")
   fun aopTest(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any? {
       println("yes man")
       return joinPoint.proceed()
   }
```

@Around's AOP method works but @DeclareError's error not works.
Can't @DeclareError use in intellij and gradle environment?

I've searched about @DeclareError but sources Most examples were Eclipse environments.

Comment: I fixed the tags in your question, using _kotlin_ instead of _java_, because you are using Kotlin, which might well be a decisive factor why this is not working. But the answer depends on your usage scenario. Are you really using native AspectJ or rather proxy-based Spring AOP in your Spring Boot application? You are talking about Gradle, but not showing your build and run configurations. Please publish an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, so I can reproduce the problem. Your situation is complex, simply posting the aspect is not enough in this case. Thank you.